# How to find $\sum_{i=1}^n\left\lfloor i\sqrt{2}\right\rfloor$ A001951 A Beatty sequence: a(n) = floor(n*sqrt(2)).

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, radicals, ceiling-and-floor-functions, diophantine-approximation

[A001951 A Beatty sequence: a(n) = floor(n*sqrt(2)).](http://oeis.org/A001951)

If $n = 5$ then

$$\left\lfloor1\sqrt{2}\right\rfloor+ \left\lfloor2\sqrt{2}\right\rfloor + \left\lfloor3\sqrt{2}\right\rfloor +\left\lfloor4 \sqrt{2}\right\rfloor+ \left\lfloor5\sqrt{2}\right\rfloor
= 1+2+4+5+7 = 19$$

Sequence from $1$ to $20$ is:

$S=\{1,2,4,5,7,8,9,11,12,14,15,16,18,19,21,22,24,25,26,28\}$

I want to find answer for $n = 10^{100}$.

Comment: Clearly $10^{100}$ is large enough for any asymptotic behaviour to take place. Are you looking for an exact value of $a_{10^{100}}$ or an approximation?

Comment: @Hugh if possible both of them :)

Comment: The asymptotic behaviour is simple. For large $i$ we have $[i\sqrt{2}] \approx i\sqrt{2}$. The sum of $i\sqrt{2}$ for all terms up to $10^{100}$ is easy to obtain. If you're willing to, you could also assume that on average the terms are rounded down by 0.5 and you can make a correction for this.

Comment: @Hugh exact value

Comment: You said you wanted both exact and asymptotic. It's quite rude to ignore my answer and give a two word response for what more you want

Comment: @Hugh I'm sorry. that is because my poor English. I can not good explain  in English.

Comment: @Hugh I found this http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BeattySequence.html

Comment: Actually, $i\sqrt{2}-[i\sqrt{2}]$ is equidistributed on $[0,1)$, so finding asymptotic behavior is the best we can.
The values of averaged sum behaves just like $\frac{\sqrt{2}n+\sqrt{2}-1}{2}$.

Comment: @HyJu Are you assuming that it is equidistributed? Of course it is likely to be equidistributed, we expect an irrational number like $\sqrt{2}$ to act like that, but it doesn't have to act like that. Do you know any theorem for this?

Comment: @Hugh Yes it is. See link. For a proof, read the Fourier analysis textbook written by E.M.Stein and R.Shakarchi.

Comment: @HyJu does it help? http://oeis.org/A001951

Comment: Related question (with no answers at the moment): [Is there a closed form of the sum $\sum _{n=1}^x\lfloor n \sqrt{2}\rfloor$](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/2029455)

Comment: @MartinSleziak I need nearest answer then I will round to integer value

Comment: @HyJu is it sqrt(2) * n or sqrt(2*n)? and Is 1 const value?

Comment: I attached it to an answer. See below.

Comment: @HyJu I test this by code its not worked with all numbers but worked very close in number less than 10^5 but not work with 10^30 or greater

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Let $S(\alpha,n) = \sum_{k=1}^n \lfloor \alpha k \rfloor$ for $\alpha$ some irrationnal positive number.

if $\alpha \ge 2$ we let $\beta = \alpha-1$ and you get
$S(\alpha,n) = S(\beta,n) + \sum_{k=1}^n k \\
= S(\beta,n) + n(n+1)/2$

if $1 < \alpha < 2$, there is a theorem that says if $\beta$ satisfies $\alpha^{-1} + \beta^{-1} = 1$, then the sequences $\lfloor \alpha n \rfloor$ and $\lfloor \beta n \rfloor$ for $n \ge 1$ partition $\Bbb N$ (not counting $0$)

Therefore, letting $m = \lfloor \alpha n \rfloor$, $S(\alpha,n) + S(\beta, \lfloor m/\beta \rfloor) = \sum_{k=1}^m k = m(m+1)/2$
Also, $\lfloor m/ \beta \rfloor = m - \lceil m/\alpha \rceil = m- n = \lfloor (\alpha-1)n \rfloor$.

Then, letting $n' = \lfloor (\alpha-1)n \rfloor $ you have
$S(\alpha,n) = (n+n')(n+n'+1)/2 - S(\beta,n')$

So those two formulas give you a very fast way to compute $S$ if you can compute $n' = \lfloor (\alpha-1) n \rfloor$

---

In your case, $\alpha = \sqrt 2$, so you begin in the second case where you get $\beta = 2+\sqrt 2$. Since the sequence of $\alpha$s you get is periodic, you can get a recurrence formula :

Let $n' = \lfloor (\sqrt 2 -1) n \rfloor$,

$S(\sqrt 2,n) = (n+n')(n+n'+1)/2 - S(2+\sqrt 2,n') \\
= (n+n')(n+n'+1)/2 - S(\sqrt 2,n') - n'(n'+1) \\
 = nn'+n(n+1)/2-n'(n'+1)/2 - S(\sqrt 2,n')$

For example this tells you that $S(\sqrt 2,5) = 22 - S(\sqrt 2, 2) = 22 - 3 + S(\sqrt 2, 0) = 19.$

---

Since at each step $n$ is approximately multiplied by $\sqrt 2 - 1$, the arguments decrease exponentially. For $n = 10^{100}$ you need approximately $\lceil {100 \log {10}/\log ({1\over(\sqrt 2-1)})} \rceil = 262$ steps to complete the recursion. This is basically equivalent to computing the powers of $(\sqrt 2-1)$ with enough precision and should be doable quickly on any computer.

Comment: @mercio The same question, how can it be done for say $e$? Could you show an example for it as it's greater than 2 like $S(5,e)$? Thanks

Comment: @IndoUbt um do you have any difficulty when applying the two formulas for $S(e,5)$ ?

Comment: you didn't replace $n$ with $5$ and didn't compute the value of $n'$ ? well $e$'s continued fraction has some regularity (though it is not periodic) so in this case you are in luck that you can have some kind of recursion, but in general, continued fractions can look like anything.

Comment: @mercio What if $0 < \alpha < 1$ ? I got it while I was trying to do $S(e, 5)$.

Comment: Can I do something similar in case a > 2 for a similar sum: sum(floor(a * k)^2, 1 <= k <= n)? Case 1 < a < 2 works out the same.

Comment: For anyone wondering, the name of the theorem is Rayleigh's theorem.

Comment: I am wondering how this can help prove that $\sum_{k=1}^n (-1)^{ \lfloor k(\sqrt{2}-1) \rfloor } \geq 0$ for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$

Comment: @JohnStrood, if $0 < \alpha < 1$ then let $\beta = \alpha + 1$, and then $S(\alpha,n) = S(\beta,n) - n(n+1)/2$.

Comment: @JohnStrood, for $e$ the complementary Beatty sequence base is $1/(1-1/e) = e/(e-1) > 1$.

Comment: @mercio Can you or someone clarify how you say that S(α,n)+S(β,⌊m/β⌋) = ∑_{k=1}^{m} k? And what's the process that leads you to sum those quantities and pick m=⌊αn⌋? I am lost here...

Comment: @mercio I lost when you S(α,n)+S(β,⌊m/β⌋) = ∑_{k=1}^{m} k, Could you please give me more explanation?

Comment: @rusiano Now I understand why S(α,n)+S(β,⌊m/β⌋) = ∑_{k=1}^{m} k, because S(α, n) = S(α, αn/α), so S(α,n)+S(β,αn/β)=∑mk=1k.
But letting m=⌊αn⌋ so S(β,αn/β)=S(β,⌊m/β⌋).

Answer (score 7):

It is clear that, because the sequence $\{<n\sqrt{2}>\}$(the fractional part) is equidistributed over the interval $[0,1)$, we have
$$\tag{1}\sum_{n=1}^N \lfloor n\sqrt{2} \rfloor = \frac{N(N+1)\sqrt{2}}{2}-\sum_{n=1}^N <n\sqrt{2}>\label{1}$$
and for the latter sum, 
$$\tag{2}\frac{1}{N}\sum_{n=1}^N <n\sqrt{2}> \to \frac{1}{2}\label{2}$$
as $N \to \infty$.

In other words, we have
$$\tag{3}\sum_{n=1}^N \lfloor n\sqrt{2} \rfloor = \frac{N(N+1)\sqrt{2}}{2}-\frac{N}{2}+o(N)\label{3}$$
as $N \to \infty$.

So , in average, we have
$$\tag{4}\frac{1}{N}\sum_{n=1}^N \lfloor n\sqrt{2} \rfloor = \frac{(N+1)\sqrt{2}}{2}-\frac{1}{2}+o(1)\label{4}$$
and in fact the remainder term is smaller than $1/2$.

So we conclude that $\frac{1}{N}\sum_{n=1}^N \lfloor n\sqrt{2} \rfloor$(which is not an integer) is very close to the nearest integer to the number $\frac{N\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{2}-1}{2}$.

One interesting thing I observed is that we in fact have more nice decay of the error term, that is,
$$\tag{5}\frac{1}{N}\sum_{n=1}^N \lfloor n\sqrt{2} \rfloor = \frac{(N+1)\sqrt{2}}{2}-\frac{1}{2}+o(\frac{1}{N}),\label{5}$$
so, return to our original problem, we come up with
$$\tag{6}\sum_{n=1}^N \lfloor n\sqrt{2} \rfloor = \frac{N(N+1)\sqrt{2}}{2}-\frac{N}{2}+o(1)\label{6}$$
and in fact the error term is again smaller than 1/2. So the sum is the nearest integer to the number
$$\tag{7}\label{7}\frac{N(N+1)\sqrt{2}}{2}-\frac{N}{2}=\frac{N(N\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{2}-1)}{2}$$.

But the proof could possibly require more nice approximation than just the equidistribution of the sequence.
(And there seems even more faster decay of the error term!!)

++Added))

What always true in the above discussion is $\eqref{3}$ or the equivalent form $\eqref{4}$. So we can exactly figure out the average value of the Beatty sequence of $\sqrt{2}$, that is, the division of $\eqref{1}$ by $N$.

However, for the exact computation of the value of the sum $\eqref{1}$, we need more precise approximation on the error term like $\eqref{5}$ or $\eqref{6}$. Unfortunately, $\eqref{5}$ is not true and so is $\eqref{7}$.

I think the best we can do is this: For any irrational $\gamma$, let $L(\gamma)=1-|1-2<\gamma>|$. Then we have
$$\left\vert \sum_{n=1}^N \lfloor n\gamma \rfloor - \left(\frac{N(N+1)\gamma}{2}-\frac{N}{2}\right) \right\vert \leq \frac{c}{L(\gamma)}$$
with $c$ a constant irrelevant to $\gamma$ and $N$($c=2$ would actually work)

This essentially asserts that the randomness of the distribution of the sequence $\{<n\gamma>\}$ in $[0,1)$ depends on how close $<\gamma>$ is to $0$ or $1$(Note that $L(\gamma)/2$ is the minimum distance from $<\gamma>$ to $0$ and to $1$. Of course this is really a naive approximation, need to be adjusted in many ways.

Comment: This is work for little numbers. Do you know how to generate this numbers? https://oeis.org/A194104 also watch this http://oeis.org/A194102

Comment: @Sinoheh Actually, I tried numbers no more than you've tested. Try the averaged one at the middle of my answer. This must work for all large values of $N$.
Numerical test seems very interesting though. Can you show me the results?

Comment: For example: input: "23223423" your result is : 381362049543566.61858316753391048249640080000565 with halfUp is : 381362049543567 and the correct answer is :381362049543566. If you want I test with bigger number I must put my server to work until tomorrow to test 10^31. If you think it can help us I will make 1 sample for this question with 10 ^31 number

Comment: It looks like the formula is quite accurate, and the error can be $\pm 1$ and $\pm 2$. For example, if we define error(N) as the value of the last formula - the true value, then $error(72)=1$, $error(35)=-1$, $error(83652)=2$, $error(40390)=-2$. And this numbers looks random for me. I'm wondering whether it is possible to nail down the exact summation value.

Comment: And for N up to 100000, there are 12086 numbers with error=-1 and 14880 numbers with error=1 and 2 numbers with error=-2 and 12 numbers with error=2.

Comment: @xslittlegrass I don't know why there is such  number with error 12 but no number 2<with error<12. Still it is very interesting!

Comment: @HyJu Sorry that's typo, I've fixed that. Do you have any possible ideas to nail down the error?

Comment: @xslittlegrass I think the error term is very subtle one.

Comment: @HyJu It does indeed. If I change the the $\sqrt{2}$ to $\sqrt{3}$ then I get 68452 numbers with error=1 and 86 numbers with error=-1 and 6425 numbers with error=2.

Comment: @xslittlegrass I'm editing now with some consideration on the choice of irrationals.

Comment: @HyJu How do you come to the last equation? Also should $-\frac{N}{2}$ be $+\frac{N}{2}$ instead? And if we substitute $\gamma=\sqrt{2}$ into the last equation, it says the error should be bounded by $1.207$, but it is not, since we have errors $\pm 2$.

Comment: @xslittlegrass Oh, thanks. That was a typo. Also, the estimated error should be corrected, but it is a matter of constant on the numerator(for instance, 2 on the numerator will work for all irrationals).
But this is not a matter. If I have a pen, I'll try to make this more precise. The error above can be found more precisely then the above formula.

Comment: @HyJu I found a [paper](http://www.jstor.org.libezp.lib.lsu.edu/stable/10.4169/amer.math.monthly.118.06.497?seq=1) which may be interesting to look at. In this paper, the exact expression for the sum for $\gamma$ equals the golden ratio, is expressed using Fibonacci sequence. But I don't know whether it's possible to transfer to our $\gamma=\sqrt{2}$ case.

Comment: @HyJu I test formula with real big number comparation:N = 86032128652 The real answer: 5233670046269024148148 your formula answer: 5233670046269023958675.330079366

Comment: @HyJu Is there any way to find best γ?

Comment: @xslittlegrass do you find any way to transfer to $γ$?

Comment: @Sinoheh By the way your "real answer" seems incorrect. The correct one should be `5233670046269023958676`.

Comment: @xslittlegrass yes I understand

Comment: A computational evidence suggests that $S(\sqrt{2},N)=\frac{\varphi^2}{3}N^2+\frac{\sqrt{2}-1}{2}N+N\cdot I(N)$,  where $|I(N)|<1.1$  and the graph of $I(N)$ looks like that of a Fourier series, see a [sample for $1\le n\le 4096$](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aRUb9.png). See the first part of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2307822/71850) answer for more.