# Summation of rounded numbers of the form $\lfloor\alpha n\rfloor$

Tags: ceiling-and-floor-functions

We have a sequence of $\lfloor\alpha n\rfloor$, where $\alpha$ is a given irrational. I'm interested in closed-forms for
$$
\sum_{n=1}^N\lfloor\alpha n\rfloor, \sum_{n=1}^Nn\lfloor\alpha n\rfloor, \mbox{and} \sum_{n=1}^N(\lfloor\alpha n\rfloor)^2.
$$
Thanks.

EDIT: Recurrence relations would be good enough too, if they can be quickly evaluated for large $N$s, say on the order of $10^{15}$. I think I found such a recurrence for the first sum, but the latter two still stand unsolved.

EDIT2: To be precise, I need these formulas for one particular $\alpha = 1/\varphi$, which makes the sequence Hofstadter G-sequence, but I doubt it will help - there should be a universal approach for any $\alpha$.

Comment: what is the recurrence you found for the 1st ?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2052179/how-to-find-sum-i-1n-left-lfloor-i-sqrt2-right-rfloor-a001951-a-beatty-s