# Sum of modulo for first n natural numbers where divisor is irrational

Tags: sequences-and-series, modular-arithmetic

Given integer *n* and float *z* find sum *s* of modulo *z* of first *n* natural numbers i.e *1%z + 2%z + ... + n%z*. Note that **z is irrational number**!

$$ s=\sum_{i=1}^n {(i\mod z)} \\
z \ is \ irrational
$$

For my concrete case z is $$ {\sqrt 2+1}$$

I found similar problem: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-sum-modulo-k-first-n-natural-number

For my case n could be bigger than 10^100, so naive linear time solution would not work.

Comment: $i\bmod z$ just means $i-\lfloor i/z\rfloor\,z$, correct? With $n$ possibly bigger than $10^{100}$, that just looks like some programming challenge, not a practical or research problem. Ok, not much of a challenge for your particular $z$, so... $O(\log^3 N)$ should be easy.

Comment: @ProfessorVector, exactly! And how can it be calculated with only (log3)?

Comment: If it's some contest, I'd rather win it myself. ;-)

Comment: I assure you that it is not a contest and it is not possible to win for anybody :)

Comment: Why do you need an answer, then? Sums with $10^{100}$ terms are... strange.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up reducing the problem to the
$$
s=\sum_{i=1}^n {(i\mod z)} = \sum_{i=1}^n(i * z) - \sum_{i=1}^n\lfloor i*z \rfloor \\
z \ is \ irrational
$$

Solving first term is trivial and the second one could be solved using the Beatty sequence:
[How to find $\sum_{i=1}^n\left\lfloor i\sqrt{2}\right\rfloor$ A001951 A Beatty sequence: a(n) = floor(n*sqrt(2)).](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2052179/how-to-find-sum-i-1n-left-lfloor-i-sqrt2-right-rfloor-a001951-a-beatty-s)

Comment: This equation contradicts the interpretation of $i\bmod z$ you confirmed above, but both are closely related, naturally. Mercio's answer is using the same idea I'd use myself, but it's a bit confusing, since $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are used in various different meanings. Moreover, it's not clear what to do if you have $\sqrt{3}$ instead of $\sqrt{2}$.

Answer (score 2):

Sums are almost linear. I found linear regression  $$s\approx 1.20708 n+0.0506173$$
For $n=10^5$ exact sum is $120712$ while the approximation gives $120708$

For $n=2\cdot 10^5$ exact sum is $241420.917186$ and approximation is $241416.6$

Comment: Unfortunately, we can compare against the correct result only for small $n$. In general, there is no error estimate, as far as I know.

Comment: @ProfessorVector You are right. Doyou sincerely believe it can make sense looking for a sum like that "with $n$ largest than $10^{100}$"?

Comment: Yes, of course. It's relatively easy (if you can handle numbers of that magnitude) to compute the exact result for $n=10^{100}$, say.